# What is the advantage of Android's Animator object?

Tags: android, animation, canvas

Currently I'm trying to implement a simple animation: I draw on the canvas of an Surfaceview and want to move a single-colored circle smoothly across the screen.
To achieve that I calculate a slightly moved circle, draw the canvas and let the thread then sleep for a few miliseconds. This doesn't run very smoothly.
So I found the animator object of google, that was written for that use. Does it something different then my code or will it just similarly calculate the moved circle every few miliseconds?

Here is the code I use for the drawing:

```
public void run() {
    circle= new Circle(getRandPoint());
    Canvas canvas = null;
    while (running) {
        if(!circle.IsMoving()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            newPos = getRandPoint();
            circle.setNewPos(newPos);
            }
            circle.calculateMovement();
        // PAINT
        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (holder) {
                draw(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        // WAIT
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30); // Wait some time until I need to display again
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the important methods of my Circle class:

```
public void setNewPos(Point p){
        nPosX = p.x;
        nPosY = p.y;
        dx = (nPosX - posX);
        dy = (nPosY - posY);
        // normalize dx and dy and multiply it by speed
        double dxdy = Math.abs(dx+dy);
        dx = dx/dxdy;
        dy = dy/dxdy;
        dx *= speed;
        dy *= speed;
    }

    public void calculateMovement(){
        posX += dx;
        posY += dy;
}
```

Thanks for every answer.

Comment: ObjectAnimator object is querying for the initial property value before animating to the new property value. It also shows how the calls may be made multiple times.

Remember... you can work on any object, you can use this class to perform animation using any graphics system, for example: OpenGL.

ObjectAnimator is an easy way to create a animation with interaction, maybe if just need interaction can you do this from XML file for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it something different then my code or will it just similarly calculate the moved circle every few miliseconds?

Android's animation framework does a number of things that your code does not. Some of the convenient things it offers out of the box are the ability to pause animations, or play animations on different views in coordination with each other (either at the same time or in sequence, for example).

It also has the distinct benefit of already being written and tested, so you don't need to do that yourself.

There are some much bigger benefits that you can from the framework though-

First, one issue that you have in your code is that it doesn't care about when your graphics are actually rendered on screen. By blindly delaying for 30 milliseconds, you could be skipping GPU frames or performing draws that won't actually be visible to the user. The framework's animation functions are optimized to avoid these issues. This is likely the source of the jank you are seeing in your implementation.

Second, the framework provides the ability to define more [authentic motion](https://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html) through the use of interpolators. Real objects don't move in a linear fashion, so using an interpolator allows you to define more realistic motion, such as slowing down as the animation reaches the final position.